# How to valildate html:options collection in Struts 1.3?

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts, struts-1

Following `Treemap` is having all the values from database which I am passing with

```
Map<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>(map);
Iterator mapIterator = mapSet.iterator();
while (mapIterator.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) mapIterator.next();
  String keyValue = (String) mapEntry.getKey();
  String value = (String) mapEntry.getValue();
  System.out.println("Key : " + keyValue + "= Value : " + value);
}
request.setAttribute("airline_name", treeMap);
```

**In JSP page:**

```
<html:select property="airline_name_value"  styleId  = "tempId" > 
  <html:options collection="airline_name" property="key" labelProperty="key" />  
</html:select>
```

**In `ActionForm`:**

```
private String airline_name;
public String getAirline_name() {
return airline_name;
}
public void setAirline_name(String airline_name) {
this.airline_name = airline_name;
}
```

**Error:**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean under name airline_name
```

Is there any other way to use `html:options` collection tag?

Answer (score 2):

There's another way to not use `html:options` but use `html:optionsCollection` instead.

```
<html:optionsCollection property="airlines" label="value" value="key" />
```

To make this working you should map the property in the form

```
private Map<String, String> airlines;

public Map<String, String> getAirlines() {
  return airlines;
}

public void setAirlines(Map<String, String> airlines) {
  this.airlines = airlines;
}
```

in the action

```
form.setAirlines(treeMap);
```